# How to remove value, determine minimum of remaining values

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, netbeans

I need to determine the minimum value after removing the first value.

For instance is these are the numbers 0.5 70 80 90 10

I need to remove 0.5, the determine the minimum value in the remaining numbers. calweightAvg is my focus ...

The final output should be “The weighted average of the numbers is 40, when using the data 0.5 70 80 90 10, where 0.5 is the weight, and the average is computed after dropping the lowest of the rest of the values.”

EDIT: Everything seems to be working, EXCEPT during the final out put. "The weighted average of the numbers is 40.0, when using the data 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 10.0, where **70.0** (should be 0.5) is the weight, and the average is computed after dropping the lowest of the rest of the values."

So the math is right, the output is not.

EDIT: While using a class `static double weight=0.5;`to establish the weight, if the user were to change the values in the input file, that would not work. How can I change the class?

```
/*
* 
*/
package calcweightedavg;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


public class CalcWeightedAvg {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    ArrayList<Double> inputValues = getData(); // User entered integers.
    double weightedAvg = calcWeightedAvg(inputValues); // User entered weight.
    printResults(inputValues, weightedAvg); //Weighted average of integers. 

}

public class CalcWeightedAvg {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    ArrayList<Double> inputValues = getData(); // User entered integers.
    double weightedAvg = calcWeightedAvg(inputValues); // User entered weight.
    printResults(inputValues, weightedAvg); //Weighted average of integers. 

}

public static ArrayList<Double> getData() throws FileNotFoundException {

    // Get input file name.
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input File: ");
    String inputFileName = console.next();
    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);

    // 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    String inputString = in.nextLine();

    // 
    String[] strArray = inputString.split("\\s+"); //LEFT OFF HERE

    // Create arraylist with integers.
    ArrayList<Double> doubleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String strElement : strArray) {
        doubleArrayList.add(Double.parseDouble(strElement));
    }

    in.close();

    return doubleArrayList;  
}


public static double calcWeightedAvg(ArrayList<Double> inputValues){
   //Get and remove weight.
   Double weight = inputValues.get(0);
   inputValues.remove(0);

   //Sum and find min.
   double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
   double sum = 0;
   for (Double d : inputValues) {
       if (d < min) min = d;
       sum += d;
   }

   // Calculate weighted average.
   return (sum-min)/(inputValues.size()-1) * weight;


}

public static void printResults(ArrayList<Double> inputValues, double weightedAvg) throws IOException {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Output File: ");
    String outputFileName = console.next();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

    System.out.println("Your output is in the file " + outputFileName);

    out.print("The weighted average of the numbers is " + weightedAvg + ", ");
    out.print("when using the data ");
    for (int i=0; i<inputValues.size(); i++) {
        out.print(inputValues.get(i) + ", ");
    }
    out.print("\n where " + inputValues.get(0) + " is the weight, ");
    out.print("and the average is computed after dropping the lowest of the rest of the values.\n");

    out.close();
}
```

}

Comment: My bad, new to this whole thing. Sorry .. just looking for some help.

Comment: use TreeSet instead of ArrayList and your data will always be sorted without worrying about finding it

Comment: It's required to be an ArrayList .. unfortunately.

Comment: use a minheap implemented using an arraylist. you will get really fast removal of the smallest element in the list

Comment: Could you please show the math to calculate the weighted average? I am struggling to see what exactly you want since 0.5*(70+80+90+10) != 40. Either way, I will add some code and edit this portion based on your response.

Comment: 0.5 is the weight; 70+80+90+10 is the sum, now to remove to min we will be left with 70+80+90 = 240; 240*weight = 120; 120\3(excluding the min) = 40;

Comment: I've made some edits. I'm down to the very end. I'm running into issues with `static double weight=0.5;` giving me flexibility for changing input values.

Comment: @javafordummies the class variable should be initialized to 0 than changed during run-time to the correct value after reading from file. see my solution under "change for function"

Comment: Please do not deface your question after asking it. Question rolled back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do this task in a complexity of O(n) isn't a hard task.
you can use `ArrayList`'s `.get(0)` to Save weight in a temp variable, then use `.remove(0)` function which removes the first value (in this case 0.5)

then you should use a For Each loop `for (Double d : list)` to sum AND find the minimal value

afterwards subtract the minimum value from the sum. and apply weight to the sum (in this case you'll end up with 240*0.5 = 120; 120\3 = 40;

finally, you can use `ArrayList`'s `.size()`-1 function to determine the divisor.

**The problem in your code:**

- in your implementation you've removed the weight item from list. then multiplied by the first item in the list even though it's no longer the weight:

> `return (sum-min)/(inputValues.size()-1) * inputValues.get(0);`

- your calculation than was: `((70+80+90+10)-10)/(4-1) * (70) = 5600`

> ```
> if(inputValues.size() <= 1){
>        inputValues.remove(0);
>     }
> ```

- this size safeguard will not remove weight from the list. perhaps you've meant to use `>=1`
- even if that was your intention this will not result in a correct computation of your algorithm in the edge cases where size==0\1\2 I would recommend that you re-think this.

**the full steps that need to be taken in abstract code:**

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList();
        // get and remove weight
        Double weight = list.get(0);
        list.remove(0);
        // sum and find min
        double min=Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double sum=0;
        for (Double d : list) {
            if (d<min) min = d;
            sum+=d;
        }
        // subtract min value from sum
        sum-=min;
        // apply weight
        sum*=weight;
        // calc weighted avg
        double avg = sum/list.size()-1;
        // viola!
```

do take notice that you can now safely add weight back into the array list after its use via `ArrayList`'s `.add(int index, T value)` function. also, the code is very abstract and safeguards regarding size should be implemented.

**Regarding your Edit:**

it appears you're outputting the wrong variable.

> out.print("\n where " + inputValues.get(0) + " is the weight, ");

the weight variable was already removed from the list at this stage, so the first item in the list is indeed 70. either add back the weight variable into the list after you've computed the result or save it in a class variable and input it directly.

following are the implementation of both solutions. you should only use one of them not both.

**1) add weight back into list solution:**

change this function to add weight back to list:

```
public static double calcWeightedAvg(ArrayList<Double> inputValues){
   //Get and remove weight.
   Double weight = inputValues.get(0);
   inputValues.remove(0);

   //Sum and find min.
   double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
   double sum = 0;
   for (Double d : inputValues) {
       if (d < min) min = d;
       sum += d;
   }
   // Calculate weighted average. 
   double returnVal = (sum-min)/(inputValues.size()-1) * weight;
   // add weight back to list
   inputValues.add(0,weight);

   return returnVal;
}
```

**2) class variable solution:**

change for class:

```
public class CalcWeightedAvg { 

static double weight=0;
//...
}
```

change for function:

```
public static double calcWeightedAvg(ArrayList<Double> inputValues){
   //Get and remove weight.
   weight = inputValues.get(0); // changed to class variable
//...
}
```

change for output:

```
out.print("\n where " + weight + " is the weight, ");
```

Comment: Thank! However, when I tried this... my output was "The weighted average of the numbers is 29.0, when using the data 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 10.0, 
 where 70.0 is the weight, and the average is computed after dropping the lowest of the rest of the values."

Comment: Actually, i figured that part out. The only thing that isn't making sense is why it's showing 70 has me weight in the output, when it should show 0.5. I'm uploading my changes now

Comment: @javafordummies you're outputing the `inputValues.get(0)` instead of the weight variable. either add the weight variable back to the list or output it directly

Comment: this is the line i'm talking about: `out.print("\n where " + inputValues.get(0) + " is the weight, ");`

Comment: What's the best way to add it back in? Should I add it back in, in that method specifically?

Comment: if you use `inputValues.add(0,val)` the value will be added at index 0 and all subsequent values will be pushed back into their new correct position. (do take notice that this can be quite an expensive action to do when dealing with large arrays)

Comment: What is the val referring too? Sorry, I feel like an idiot.

Comment: @javafordummies it's okay, we all know the feeling of getting stuck on an assignment. that val would be the weight (in this case 0.5).

Comment: So: inputValues.add(0,weight); ?

Now, where do I put it? Haha.

Comment: When using the class variable, can I have it reference a part of the array list (before it was altered)?

My concern is if the user were to change the data in the input file, it would no longer be correct.

Comment: @javafordummies i have edited my answer to reflect the solution of adding weight back into the list. regarding user manipulation of data, since I am not fully aware of what you're planning to use this calculation for I find myself unable to think of a user-safe lock mechanism to stop every intrusion. why would a user manipulate your data? even if one does, only should it happen concurrently it would affect your results.

Comment: I don't question my professor, I just know to expect possible change in data.

Comment: Also, I really appreciate all your help

Comment: alas i don't understand your question in that regard, would you care to rephrase it?

Comment: @javafordummies as long as inputfile contains a series of doubles seperated by a whitespace in which the first value is the weight and has a total of atleast 3 values (weight and two other doubles) the answer will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the first element from `ArrayList` and calculate the minimum in the remaining you should do:

```
if(inputValues.size() <= 1) //no point in calculation of one element
   return;

inputValues.remove(0);
double min = inputValues.get(0); 
for (int i = 1; i < inputValues.size(); i++) {
     if (inputValues.get(i) < min)
           min = inputValues.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Quick question, buddy. I was leaning towards a minheap approach. Are there any issues that I am overlooking?

Comment: @DebosmitRay I don't know if there is any standard implementation of minheap in java but I know TreeSet is storing the data sets in a sorted way so basically do the same thing (different approach)

Comment: if(inputValues.size() <= 1) //no point in calculation of one element
   return;

Netbeans is not liking that return.

Comment: @javafordummies it is an extra check you can remove it

Comment: It gets me so close, I updated back the full code with your change. However, the output is still wrong. I added what it's expected to be, right above code.

Comment: @javafordummies the for loop is wrong. It is "<" not ">"

Comment: So I fixed that, however I'm getting this "The weighted average of the numbers is 30.9375, when using the data 0.5, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 10.0, 
 where 0.5 is the weight, and the average is computed after dropping the lowest of the rest of the values."

Comment: @javafordummies take a look at your second loop, now you have removed your first list element, you need to rewrite your second loop logic

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an ArrayList, this should be a piece of cake.

To remove a value from an ArrayList, just find the index of the value and call

```
myList.remove(index);
```

If 0.5 is the first element in the list, remove it with

```
inputValues.remove(0);
```

If you want to find the minimum value in an ArrayList of doubles, just use this algorithm to find both the minimum value and its index:

```
double minVal = Double.MAX_VALUE;
int minIndex = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {

    if(myList.get(i) < minVal) {
        minVal = myList.get(i);
        minIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear about your goal here. If you are required to make frequent calls to check the minimum value, a min heap would be a very good choice.

A min heap has the property that it offers constant time access to the minimum value. This [[implementation](http://www.dave-reed.com/csc321.F12/Code/MinHeap.java)] uses an ArrayList. So, you can add to the ArrayList using the `add()` method, and `minValue()` gives constant time access to the minimum value of the list since it ensures that the minimum value is always at index 0. The list is modified accordingly when the least value is removed, or a new value is added (called heapify).

I am not adding any code here since the link should make that part clear. If you would like some clarification, I would be more than glad to be of help.

**Edit**.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private static ArrayList<Double> values;
    private static Double sum = 0.0D;

    /**
     * Identifies the minimum value stored in the heap
     *   @return the minimum value
     */
    public static Double minValue() {
        if (values.size() == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return values.get(0);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new value to the heap.
     *   @param newValue the value to be added
     */
    public static void add(Double newValue) {
        values.add(newValue);
        int pos = values.size()-1;

        while (pos > 0) {
            if (newValue.compareTo(values.get((pos-1)/2)) < 0) {
                values.set(pos, values.get((pos-1)/2));
                pos = (pos-1)/2;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        values.set(pos, newValue);

        // update global sum
        sum += newValue;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the minimum value from the heap.
     */
    public static void remove() {
       Double newValue = values.remove(values.size()-1);
       int pos = 0;

       if (values.size() > 0) {
           while (2*pos+1 < values.size()) {
               int minChild = 2*pos+1;
               if (2*pos+2 < values.size() &&
                     values.get(2*pos+2).compareTo(values.get(2*pos+1)) < 0) {
                   minChild = 2*pos+2;
               }

               if (newValue.compareTo(values.get(minChild)) > 0) {
                   values.set(pos, values.get(minChild));
                   pos = minChild;
               }
               else {
                   break;
               }
           }
           values.set(pos, newValue);

       }      
       // update global sum
       sum -= newValue;
    }

    /**
     * NEEDS EDIT Computes the average of the list, leaving out the minimum value.
     *   @param newValue the value to be added
     */
    public static double calcWeightedAvg() {
        double minValue = minValue();
        // the running total of the sum took this into account
        // so, we have to remove this from the sum to get the effective sum
        double effectiveSum = (sum - minValue);

        return effectiveSum * minValue;
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        values = new ArrayList<Double>();

        // add values to the arraylist -> order is intentionally ruined
        double[] arr = new double[]{10,70,90,80,0.5};
        for(double val: arr)
            add(val);

        System.out.println("Present minimum in the list: " + minValue());    // 0.5
        System.out.println("CalcWeightedAvg: " + calcWeightedAvg());    // 125.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this whole thing.

Comment: My goal is to remove the 0.5, then determine the min of 70 80 90 10.

I need to find the weighted average of 70 80 90 10, after the min (10) is removed. 0.5 is the weight.

Comment: @javafordummies Added some code. Will update the method `calcWeightedAvg()` based on your response